# How to create ACF PRO fields programmatically using OOP?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I like ACF PRO. It's very good and power WP plugin. But...

I read [the documentations ACF PRO](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/register-fields-via-php/), but the approach isn't OOP and it looks a bit multi-line-redundant (I mean it isn't convenient to use it).

Are there any other methods to create ACF PRO fields? Maybe some good 3-rd party OOP wrapper library?

Comment: Have you tried make your own? Define "isn't convenient". ACF provides functions/methods and a very, very comprehensive visual interface so I'm not sure what you mean by this question.

Comment: @ggdx I didn't say that ACF PRO is bad. And my question isn't about "visual interface" which is really good. I hope to find the answer and will show you later.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have found and tried use [this ACF Builder](https://github.com/StoutLogic/acf-builder).

It's just ACF configuration builder but it looks good. I can define and create a new fields group programmatically. Important note, the result code is short and easy reading and we can reuse it. It exactly more short than default method:

```
<code>
$banner = new StoutLogic\AcfBuilder\FieldsBuilder('banner');
$banner
    ->addText('title')
    ->addWysiwyg('content')
    ->addImage('background_image')
    ->setLocation('post_type', '==', 'page')
        ->or('post_type', '==', 'post');

add_action('acf/init', function() use ($banner) {
    acf_add_local_field_group($banner->build());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use OOP fields creating you can use another library instead ACF Pro. I can recommend to you [Carbon Fields](https://carbonfields.net/). The same field types, locations and other. Also reed [this article](http://wpgear.org/#meta-fields). you can find same list of PHP instruments for meta fields.

And you can create self classes for using ACF Pro via PHP with OOP.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look at and will learn your links, but I meant ACF PRO exactly.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I created [ACF Code Helper](https://github.com/RadoslavGeorgiev/acf-code-helper/wiki) for situations like this.

**Upsides, compared to directly using ACF functions**

- The helper takes care of field keys, which not only makes the syntax shorter, but doesn't require much copy-pasting for conditional logic.
- There isn't that much overhead, because for the major portion of code (the fields) the syntax follows ACF, so you can use the ACF docs instead of an additional wiki.

**Downsides**

- Although the syntax is a bit shortened, it is still mostly array-based.
- You need to keep an extra plugin activated. Not much of an issue if you clone the helper within your theme and include it.